# Formula to convert WGS84 to BT68 and to Borneo Rectified Screw Orthomorphic

Tags: arcmap, coordinate-system, orthorectification

I am doing research about converting the coordinate system from Wgs84 to Rectify Skew Orthomorphic Borneo (BRSO) map projection system which is very useful for Sabah and Sarawak but I have two problems:

1. When I convert the WGS84 to BRSO, I only can convert until the part BT68..and don't know the formula convert BT68 to BRSO.
2. When I convert the BRSO to WGS84, I only from BRSO to BT68 and can't continue to WGS84. Cause don't know the formula.

I will attach some concept of the Convertion.

Do you have an idea or formula that can let me know?

[image: concept of convertion]
[image: concept of Convertion]

Comment: Anyone have the formula for box1,2, 3 and 4?

Comment: in the question, you state that youcan get from wgs84 to bt68, but then you can't get from bt68 to wgs84? Can you do any of the transformations? Do you have access to PROJ.4/GDAL/QGIS or other GIS or projections software? Do you want to implement the mathematics yourself? What programming language?

Comment: Here i mean i only can complete for datum conversion (WGS84 to timbalai / Timbalai to WGS84) but don't know the formula for coordinate transformation (geo timbalai to brso / brso to geo timbalai).